# How to display public images in browser?

Tags: javascript, html, vite

I have a following folder structure

```
.
├── public
├──└──images
├──└── image1.png
├──└── image2.png
├── src
├── vite.config.js
└── [...]
```

### vite.config.js

```
const path = require('path')

export default {
    root: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    server: {
        port: 3000,
        hot: true
    },
    publicDir: 'public'
}
```

How can I access images under public folder ? I tried this from browser

- http://127.0.0.1:3000/public/images/image1.png
- http://127.0.0.1:3000/images/image1.png

But it gives "Not found"

Can anybody help me ?

Comment: 'Can somebody help me?' is not a "real question" by our community's standards! Can you please [read this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/11107541) to learn why and how to ask a better question? You can also see [ask] for guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docs [here](https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html)

publicDir

> Directory to serve as plain static assets. Files in this directory are served at / during dev and copied to the root of outDir during build, and are always served or copied as-is without transform. **The value can be either an absolute file system path or a path relative to project root**.

So your publicDir must be relative to the root address you set, so you need to either change the root address to the folder above src, or change the `publicDir` path.

Comment: `publicDir: './public'` I have tried this

Comment: that is not the path relative to the root. The relative path would be `publicDir: '../public'`

Comment: I have tried `../public` too

Comment: Thanks @White Wizard, I need to restart then it worked. Thanks